# Как обратно получить значение из функции в Python?

Tags: python, функции, переменные

У меня в функции много переменных, и мне нужно вытащить одну из них в основной код.

```
def code(q_f_code):
    correct=0
    q_f_code2=q_f_code
    while q_f_code!=0:
        x=randint(1,123)
        y=randint(1,123)
        z=int(input())
        if x**y==z:
            correct=+1
            q_f_code=q_f_code-1
        else:
            correct=-1
            q_f_code=q_f_code-1
    print('у тебя {:} из {:} правильных ответов'.format(correct, q_f_code2))
code(q_f_code=int(input('Введите количество вопросов, которое хотите получить: ')))
```

Мне нужно вывести переменную "correct", но и функция должна работать. Я хочу использовать функцию "correct" в следущей функции, которую напишую

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20global&searchOn=3

Comment: Просто верните ее из функции после `print('у тебя {:} из {:} ...` через `return` и поместите в переменную

Comment: А вот когда в универах учили `Pascal`, то в нём было разделение на функции и процедуры и студенты сразу узнавали про то, что функция - это что-то, что возвращает значение. А сейчас связь утеряна ))

Comment: Забудьте о такой вещи, как "вытащить одну переменную из функции". Вы вообще не должны знать, что происходит в функции. Вам доступно только то, что в функции стоит после return. Если вам нужно значение переменной ``correct``, то пишите ``return correct``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно переменную correct сделать глобальной

```
from random import randint


def code(q_f_code):
    
    global correct

    
    correct = 0
    q_f_code2 = q_f_code
    
    while q_f_code != 0:
        
        x = randint(1,123)
        y = randint(1,123)
        z = int(input())
        
        if x**y == z:
            correct += 1
            #q_f_code = q_f_code - 1
            
        else:
            correct -= 1
            #q_f_code = q_f_code - 1
            
        q_f_code = q_f_code - 1

    print('у тебя {:} из {:} правильных ответов'.format(correct, q_f_code2))

code(q_f_code=int(input('Введите количество вопросов, которое хотите получить: ')))


#Проверка выводом
print(correct)
```

Но более правильно будет если функция будет возвращать эту переменную:

```
from random import randint


def code(q_f_code):
    
    correct = 0
    q_f_code2 = q_f_code
    
    while q_f_code != 0:
        
        x = randint(1,123)
        y = randint(1,123)
        z = int(input())
        
        if x**y == z:
            correct += 1
            #q_f_code = q_f_code - 1
            
        else:
            correct -= 1
            #q_f_code = q_f_code - 1
            
        q_f_code = q_f_code - 1

    print('у тебя {:} из {:} правильных ответов'.format(correct, q_f_code2))

    return correct #Возвращаем локальную версию correct



#|
#V   это глобальная версия, названия необязательно должны совпадать
correct = code(q_f_code = int(input('Введите количество вопросов, которое хотите получить: ')))


#Проверка выводом
print(correct)
```

То что функция теперь возвращает переменную никак не влияет на её работу

Соблюдайте [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) и не забывайте ставить пустые строки что бы читать можно было